# невидимый курсор в Canvas tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, cursor

Как сделать так, чтобы курсор не был виден, когда он наводится на `Canvas`?

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
canv=Canvas(root,highlightthickness=0,bg='white',cursor='???')
canv.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0, bg='blue', cursor="None")
canv.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]